The prevalence of inline "enter image description here" links indicates a UX problem
"enter image description here" is such a common sight, I think it's obvious there's a UX problem here.
Some thoughts:

Should SO block submission if the string exists?
Why are these links to images and not embedded images?
Maybe we just need a different flow that encourages setting an image description more obviously.

There's also a accessibility issue / wcag issue here. Not sure if SO cares about WCAG compliance, but this would fail that test.
Example of a question with this problem:


The SG probably would address many of these, however, SO refuse to send users there, so we can't have "nice things."

Are you asking about the 1-rep users who can yet inline images? They aren't doing anything wrong. The system deliberately does not let them show images.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz added an example via a screenshot. This is a very common sight in many questions. I wasn't aware that there's a reputation gate for this

@Evert Experienced users are expected to take a look at these images and add a ! if they are a useful for the question. As soon as the ! is added, the image will show up

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ah interesting. As an experienced user, I didn't know. That said, I think this is still a pretty poor UX. Users should be encouraged to write alt text, or encouraged to embed code in case they're sharing screenshots of their editor.

related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129833/warn-new-users-earlier-that-they-cannot-post-links-or-images

Should SO block submission if the string exists? I like the idea.

"there's a UX problem here" -- nope, PEBKAC. You really don't need to be a rocket scientist to figure out what you're expected to do there, it literally says it. There's no excuse at all for users who leave it untouched and hit submit.

(Nearly) Ten years in I also did not know about the use of !. I've been copying the URL, removing the link, and then adding it back again. Can't wait to try that ! out.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I don't think that's "expected" for experienced users to do that. At least, I've never seen such guidance. Sometimes images don't need to be (or are better off not) embedded, such as when they're ancillary to the question or are so big that they make users have to scroll significantly. Likewise, just adding a ! is less than ideal. It's better to add a wrapper of [!]() (or whatever the exact syntax is) so that the link is not only embedded but also a clickable link to open the full version via a direct link.

@Evert "There's also a accessibility issue / wcag issue here. Not sure if SO cares about WCAG compliance, but this would fail that test." What exactly is the issue? That SO doesn't require a caption be manually written by the user when adding an image? Note that accessibility issues with user-submitted content don't affect WCAG compliance of the site itself.

@Evert All my comments have been genuine efforts to improve the quality of this question, ironically. Sorry if you feel they're bad faith--I actually get the same vibe from you. As for your quote, that's not a claim, it's a correction to your claim that user-contributed content on a social media site affect the WCAG compliance score of the site. But that's not how it works. Sites that allow users to post content can't typically control how accessible the content a user posts is. It's the content of the site itself that matters for its WCAG compliance score.

@Evert The font and font color and rendered markup of your post above are part of the site, and thus fair game for WCAG compliance scoring for the site "Meta Stack Overflow". The contents of your post are not, because they're not part of the site. It's up to each user to ensure the content they add to the site is accessible, should they care about that. But like all other user-generated content, Stack Overflow is not particularly liable or responsible for inaccessible user-generated content.

And, just so there's no confusion, I do think it's better for accessibility when images have alt text.

@TylerH here's a relevant stack overflow question with sources that failing to force users to submit content with an accessible way might at least reduce compliance to 'partial'. I think it counts, especially since options exist to do something better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62788578/wcag-2-1-aa-compliance-and-user-generated-content-what-do-you-do-with-content

@Evert The accepted answer there indicates two options, one of which is "accept it, because you're not responsible". The other is not possible for Stack Overflow (or any social media site) because it does not scale whatsoever. As the other answer there makes fairly clear, you're not responsible for 3rd party content when you provide methods for that content to be made accessible. Stack Overflow provides an option for users to add alt text. It's the user's responsibility to make use of that option.

@TylerH Sure, I stand by my original point that generally encouraging more users to supply the alt text through UI changes improves both compliance and accessibility. The only intepretation where this is not true is if you see WCAG compliance as boolean and not as a gradient where you're encouraged to do as much as you can, within reason.


There's a warning about this text (not sure if it triggers without something formatted as an image however). Here is the most recent version. It does not prevent post submission, which is fine. It's easier to search for posts with the default message (so they can be edited) than to find images with bad alt text that was added to get around an error message.

There's an undocumented new user restriction that prevents formatted images from being posted by low rep users.

While it would be great for people to do things for the sake of accessibility, it's hardly a motivator for many. In the case of questions on SO specifically, I think it would be better to explain that not including the code as text means your question will be closed. (No, it shouldn't be alt text, at least not most of what I see.) However, the warning message is the same on all sites.



RE: #2, there's also a recent-ish bug that prevents users from adding images altogether, due to miscalculating how much of the post's content is text and how much is the image. I've been unable to edit at least half a dozen posts over the last month or two to add alt text or otherwise improve the posts because of this bug.

Nice to see that improvements are being made in this area. Assuming that this is already in production, my own anecdotal evidence is suggests that people probably still miss this (or don't care)

"There's an undocumented new user restriction that prevents formatted images from being posted by low rep users." It's not undocumented if you count your previous answer to another Meta question ;)

@TylerH I run into far more problems due to questions with unacceptable titles.

@KarlKnechtel well, fixing the title is doable. The problem I mention is that the system itself blocks me from making any kind of edit (other than inline tag edits) when this bug pops up.


I think it's obvious there's a UX problem here.

It's already very easy to do the right thing - after uploading the image, the UI generates the necessary Markdown and leaves the placeholder text selected, so you can type the replacement right away. (Of course, this doesn't help much for someone who wants to add images after writing some prose).
If you want to make it harder to do the wrong thing, then you're talking about e.g. giving an error message if the text is left at this default. I can guarantee that this would just result in a flood of images labelled "image" or "img" or - worse - "the code".
These images weren't inlined because, as Laurel says, the system deliberately disallows new users from inlining images by filtering the exclamation mark out of the Markdown. This is deliberate.
Nobody wants to try to give accurate alt text to these images because they should not have been posted in the first place.
On a technical level, it's not possible to prevent new users from posting links to images, without preventing them from posting off-site links entirely (perhaps it would be possible to use some kind of whitelisting for links to previous questions). Which I'm honestly not entirely opposed to. It would at least mean that spammers don't get even a single page load with their links intact.
On a social level, it's impossible to ensure this kind of WCAG compliance for user-generated content. (Here's what the W3C has to say about it.)

For what it's worth I'm not prescribing a specific solution, but the reality is that a significant amount of questions end up with this useless text. Maybe you're right and there's nothing that can be done, but I see a fairly large amount of these in otherwise well-formatted questions, this suggests to me that there might at least be some subset that would make an effort if they were railroaded into providing an alt text at least.

If you want to make it harder to do the wrong thing, then you're talking about e.g. giving an error message if the text is left at this default. Or a text box asking for "Image description (alt text)" before uploading the image itself. I can guarantee that this would just result in a flood of images labelled "image" or "img" or - worse - "the code". Yes, but will the number of those mislabeled images be less than the current number of "enter image description here"?

@beaker I'm kinda pessimistic about it, I'd say the difference would be negligible, and it would be harder to find them. I just don't expect much from someone who just happily posts such a thing and buggers off. | Maybe automatically close the question that contains it (Needs details or clarity) and shove it into a review queue, but that would probably just saturate the reviews very quickly.

@DanMašek That's certainly a possibility. I can't count the number of times I've read a post and wanted to ask the OP if that's really the way that they wanted their post to look. The question is, just how easy do you have to make it for someone to do the right thing before they'll do it, and is it worth the effort. Prompting for description text seems rather low-effort, though, and you could have it default to the existing "enter image description here" for those who are really, really, fundamentally opposed to posting a decent question.

@beaker True. I suppose it does already pop up a little dialog-like thing even when you paste an image into the editor, so an edit box there probably wouldn't hurt too much.
